# Stop nosetests from printing logging information?

Tags: python, django, nosetests

How do I prevent nosetests from interspersing logging output inside the output from its tests?  I've just adding logging to my Django code like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def home_page(request, template):
    device = get_device_capabilities(request)
    device_type = get_device_type(device)
    logger.info("device_type = " + device_type)
    logger.info("screen_width = " + str(screen_width))
```

When I run the tests like this:

```
nosetests --nocapture
```

I get this:

```
[04/15/2014 02:42:57 PM] INFO [apps.home.views:24] device_type = computer
[04/15/2014 02:42:57 PM] INFO [apps.home.views:25] screen_width = 800
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 230 tests in 42.521s

OK
```

I'm just getting started with raising exceptions and logging information and I certainly don't want my test output littered with the output from my logger statements.  I thought the "--nocapture" flag was supposed to prevent this.  I've skimmed all the nosetest documentation and didn't see anything else that would help.  Am I missing something?  Is there a way to stop nosetests from including my logger messages in its output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to those who provided an answer to my question.  I chose not to implement [@amezhenin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23095523/3811484)'s solution as it was too different from how I run my tests and I didn't want to change.  [@Oleksiy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23138624/3811484)'s solutions got rid of some logging messages but not all of them.  I didn't quite get what [@gardenunez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23096065/3811484) was getting at but that's my fault.

After more research, I realized that I was specifying the nosetest argument incorrectly.  It's not `--nocapture` as I indicated in my initial question but rather [`--nologcapture`](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=#cmdoption--nologcapture).  When I specified this argument, all of my logging messages were hidden.

Comment: Doesn't `--nologcapture` _disable_ the logging plugin, resulting in the log messages appearing inline?

Answer (score 6):

You can always run nose with `--logging-clear-handlers` to clear all other logging handlers.

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you to put something like this into your `settings.py`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    # disable loggers output
    LOGGING["loggers"] = {}
```

btw, I using `nose` and `doctests` for testing purposes so my full template looks like this:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    # add Nose to INSTALLED_APPS for running tests
    INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_nose',)
    TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
    NOSE_ARGS = ['--with-doctest']
    # change DB to sqlite3, when running test for speedup
    DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
    # disable loggers output
    LOGGING["loggers"] = {}
```

**UPD.** Forgot to tell that I run test with `python manage.py test`, that is why I can refer to `'test'` in `sys.argv`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)` or `logging.disable(logging.NOTSET)`

It will disable logging calls with the specified severity level.